# Modal Segue View Controller Preservation

Tags: ios, uitableview, segue, uikit-state-preservation

I have a quick question. I have a `ViewController` (parent) that has a `UITableView` in it. Within that view contains a button triggering a modal segue to another `viewController` (child) with a `UITableView`. The child `viewController` acts as a filter to update the parent's table. My goal is to preserve the state of the filter `viewController` (child) after dismissal, so I can go back and update the filter selection.

After researching, I have found the docs contain information on preserving the state of the application as a whole, in situations where the app closes, etc. I am unsure if this is the sort of approach I need in order to preserve this `viewController` after dismissal.

Links are here:

[Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html)

[Blog Walkthrough](http://blog.ideveloper.tv/introduction-to-ui-state-preservation-restoration-in-ios6/)

Is this the proper way of approaching this or do I have it all wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using delegation to pass the child view controller back to the parent and storing the entire view controller as a variable in the parent. That way, the child view controller's life cycle is as long as the parents. Also, I could reload the existing child view controller when calling for that specific segue.

Answer (score 0):

Check    [NSUserDefaults Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Example:-

For retrive state:

```
 NSString *value=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Type"];
```

Save state:-

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:@"FilterType" forKey:@"Type"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```